# Swift / how to change the color of the button text in a xib file

Tags: ios, swift

I have a xib file as custom menu.
I want to change the button's text color once the button has been pressed.

This is the code handling the tap:

```
    let rulerMenu = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("rulerMenu", owner: self, options: nil).last) as! RulerMenu
    rulerMenu.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 112, self.view.bounds.size.width, 48)
    self.view.addSubview(rulerMenu)

    rulerMenu.mmBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.mmBtnFunc), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And that is the code I've started implementing as action for the button.

```
    func mmBtnFunc() {
    let rulerMenu = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("rulerMenu", owner: self, options: nil).last) as! RulerMenu
    rulerMenu.mmBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.uIColorFromHex(0xFB61CF), forState: .Normal)
}
```

The color doesn't change at all.
I have tryed to add `self.view.addSubview(rulerMenu)` to the `mmBtnFunc()` function and then the menu popped of again with the color changed. But I don't want it to "re animate". I just want the color to change.

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Did you configure the style of the button as custom?

Comment: erm. no. I've just tryed, but now the button is noticeable bigger, the button doesnt seem to reacting on taps anymore and it's color isn't changing, too.

Comment: as said, the color of the button does change, if I add self.view.addSubview(rulerMenu), but than the view does re-open

Comment: ps by "style" you mean type? what is "system" by preselection

Comment: I see now, what about if you try this: an action target usually has an argument so try change your function prototype to this func mmBtnFunc(button: UIButton) and then change directly it's color. After this change you will need to update the action selector with something like this #selector(ViewController.mmBtnFunc(_:))

Comment: that did it. feel free to answer, I'll accept

Comment: thank you. ps. it would help me, if you would write a second function called cmBtnFunc what changes the color of the button of mmBtnFunc back to white... if you have any idea

Comment: ps: but cmBtnFunc has it's own button... so kinda tricky I guess?

Comment: for that case maybe I try to access to superview of cmBtnFunc button, assuming it's in the the same view of mmBtn, and then access mmBtn and change it's color. If the buttons aren't in the same view the only solution is saving its reference somewhere

Comment: thank you for your help @tx2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your problem try this: an action target usually has an argument, so, try change your function prototype to this `func mmBtnFunc(button: UIButton)` and then change directly buttons's color. After this change you will need to update the action selector like this `#selector(ViewController.mmBtnFunc(_:))`